# Correcting a Task

Tags: python, dictionary

after I tried to add or change the following code (without success) to get it work, I am now trying to get help from you guys. This is a work of a newbie in python but unfortunately so am I and I have no clue how to make it work. The literature I use, has not the same Examples I could use. Greeting to all of you.

```
def fun (arg0 , arg ):
fun1 = None
for i in arg :
    if i not in ' aeiouAEIOU ':
        fun1 += 1
        fun2 {i} = 1
        fun3 =+ i
return [ fun1 fun2 fun3 ]

def morefun ( arrg ):
e, o, u = fun ( arrg )
print ('here : ', u)
print ('here , too : ', e)
o = list (o); o. sort ()
for n in o:
    print n, end =' - '
print

par = 'Was it a car or a cat I saw ?'
morefun ( par )
```

Comment: Do you atleast know what you want to do/achieve?

Comment: No, thats also a huge problem in understanding. "Also, try
and find out what the script was supposed to do"

Comment: Sorry I am not able to get you. If you do not know what you want to do, why do you want to do the task?

Comment: You can't add `None` and an `int` object as you do `fun1 += 1`. Also you can't add to a variable before it's defined: `fun3 =+ i`

Comment: Much clearer!. Okay, your code contains some invalied syntaxes, indentation problems, etc. Please try to learn some python basics and try to understand your code. Then, you will be able to clear some errors. Later, you can ask for the ones for which you are able to solve it on your own.

Comment: for me it looks like it want to count all consonant letters. (fun1 = number consonant letters, fun2 = how many consonant letters are found for each consonant, fun3 = print string without vowel letters. 
In the end print the total number and the sentence without vowels and print all consonant in order. (there are many mistakes in that code anyway)

Comment: Thanks @Boendal, i needed a hint like that, just to know on what I am aiming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I fixed the code and got the output (in the way I interpret it).
It was more out of curiousity.

```
def fun (arg ):
    fun1 = 0
    fun2 = {}
    fun3 = ""
    for i in arg :
        if i not in ' aeiouAEIOU ':
            fun1 += 1
            fun2[i] = fun2.get(i, 0) + 1
            fun3 += i
    return fun1, fun2, fun3

def morefun ( arrg ):
    e, o, u = fun ( arrg )
    print ('here : ', u)
    print ('here , too : ', e)
    o = list (o)
    o. sort ()
    for n in o:
        print(n, end =' - ')
    print

par = 'Was it a car or a cat I saw ?'
morefun ( par )
```

And with the output:

```
here :  Wstcrrctsw?
here , too :  11
? - W - c - r - s - t - w -
```

As mentioned what the code do:
1. Print String without vowels and blanks
2. Print the length of the String
3. Print all letters in alphabetical order (Ascii) with a '-' between them.

Some comments:

1. I don't know why the function fun() used to have 2 parameters, the
   1st wasn't used so I deleted it
2. the information about the number of letter in the String is lost when the dict is converted to a list, maybe the intention was there to order it at the number of occurrences?
3. I didn't change the name of the variables (even if the naming is awful) to give a link to the question.
4. This is my interpretation. There are still some variations possible (like that mentioned in point 1 and 2)